# typescript project reference to shared project fails to resolve

Tags: typescript, project-reference

I'm trying to use Typescript Project references between 2 projects: `client` and `shared`
the `client/tsc -b` process succeeds. but, on runtime imports of `shared` files fail.

the project structure is very simple:

```
./client
./client/tsconfig.json
./client/src
./client/src/app-load.tsx
./shared
./shared/tsconfig.json
./shared/src
./shared/src/validation-utils.ts
```

> content of **./client/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es2015",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "build",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "types": ["react", "react-native", "jest"],
        "paths": {
      "@shared/*": [
        "../shared/src/*"
      ]
    }
    },
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "exclude": ["android", "App.js", "ios", "build", "node_modules"],
    "references": [{ 
        "path": "../shared"
    }]
}
```

> content of **./shared/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
  },
  "references": []
}
```

> import used in **./client/src/app-load.tsx**

```
import { isEmailValid } from "@shared/validation-utils";
```

> error message on runtime
>
> > Unable to resolve "@shared/validation-utils" from "build/app-load.js"
> >     Failed building JavaScript bundle.

I've also tried replacing `rootDir` in `client/tsconfig.json` with

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*",
  "../shared/**/*"
],
```

like seen in other issues, still no success.

has anyone got an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm trying to figure this out as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73029263/react-ts-cannot-add-private-shared-project-references-to-react-project